# Do Catholics have an "Apocrypha" or just a "Bible"?

Tags: catholicism, terminology, apocrypha, catholic-bible

Pardon my ignorance here, but I am just wondering if the Apocrypha is labeled as such by Catholics?

To clarify, a Protestant would refer to the 66 books of Protestant Scripture as "the Bible", and to the "extra" books in the Catholic Bible as "the Apocrypha". What I am wondering is whether:

**A)** Catholics have a "Bible" which includes "the Apocrypha" as well as 66 other books, or

**B)** Catholics just have a "Bible" and reject the label "Apocrypha"

If the answer is **A**, do the "66 other books" have a label as well?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Neither of your options is correct. Catholics typically refer to what Protestants call the Apocrypha (1-2 Macabees, Sirach, etc.) as *deuterocanonical* books, and they do include them in the Bible as inspired, God-given writings.

They were in use in the church from before the NT times, and IIRC, it was Jerome that gave them the name "apocrypha" and the Council of Trent that established them as deuterocanonical. See [Development of the Old Testament Canon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Development_of_the_Old_Testament_canon) and [Apocrypha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apocrypha) in the Wikipedia.